# wifi working, ping is also fine but no internet connection in browser

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, internet, ping

I am new to stackoverflow. I recently encounterd a problem in which ping works fine but the internet is not working iin the browser. Please Please help me out.
The output of `ipconfig /all` looks like:

```
Windows IP Configuration
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : arpita
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : browserinfo.org

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual  Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B0-10-41-D4-60-07
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 14-58-D0-C5-78-D2
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::951f:3872:2052:7eb2%4(Preferred)
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.108(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 16 September 2017 03:02:48 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 16 September 2017 05:02:48 PM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.7.254
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 152328400
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-88-EA-C8-14-58-D0-C5-78-D2

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.11
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

```
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B0-10-41-D4-60-05
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

The output of `ping localhost` is:

```
Pinging arpita [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Please help me output. I have tried `netsh winsock reset catalog`
The output of `netsh int ip reset reset.log` is :

```
`Resetting Interface, OK!
 Resetting , failed.
 Access is denied.

 Resetting , OK!
 Restart the computer to complete this action.`
```

I have also tried `netsh advfirewell` `ipconfig /flushdns` `ipconfig /registerdns` `rout /f` without any luck. Please, Please help me out. It's really frustating without lan.

Edit: I am using the Intranet of College. Other friends of mine also can't ping `8.8.8.8` but can ping the proxy servers just like me. i somehow feel that DNS is not an issue. When I open the browser it asks for "Proxy Credentials" and tries to get connected(blue circle rotating) but it get stuck and shows "Performing TLS Handshake". This thing happens across all browsers that I have tried.

Comment: Can you ping outside of localhost?

Comment: Check if the browser is set to use a proxy (and remove it if so)

Comment: @HerbWolfe yep I can ping outside of localhost.

Comment: @Aganju that was already removed.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are a few *potential* problems here. I'll cover them one at a time.

### Disable IPv6

First, it's possible your computer is attempting to communicate via ipv6 and failing. This is a surprisingly common problem when Windows thinks you have ipv6 support but your ISP does not, in fact, fully support it.

You can disable ipv6:

1. Press the <kbd>[image: win10key]</kbd>
   +<kbd>R</kbd> key.
2. Type `control ncpa.cpl` into the run dialog and click `Ok`.
3. Right click on the network adapter you are using
4. Click `Properties` from the drop down.
5. Scroll down to where you see `Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)` and uncheck the box next to it.
6. Click Ok.

You may have to restart for the settings to take effect.

If this turns out not to be the problem you can simply re-check the ipv6 feature and re-start to re-enable it.

### Fix Your DNS Config

I notice you have an RFC1918 IP address for your DNS server. In addition, the DNS ip is not part of the subnet your computer is on. There are two primary circumstances where this would be correct. 1): Your computer is on a large company intranet that is subdivided into multiple subnets and has a DNS server on another part of the intranet with a router handling communication between parts. 2): Your ISP uses RFC1918 ip addresses internally (uncommon, but not unheard of). In most cases, however, this would be an invalid configuration.

It's also possible there is simply something wrong with the DNS server, either permanently or temporarily.

First thing to check is to see if you can use DNS:

1. Open the command prompt
2. Type `nslookup annapuma.onsite-crt.com`.

You should see:

```
Server:  [DNS SERVER HOSTNAME]
Address:  [DNS SERVER IP ADDRESS]

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    annapuma.onsite-crt.com
Address:  144.217.115.63
```

3. If you get a different result or you get an error message try `nslookup annapuma.onsite-crt.com 8.8.8.8` instead. This will use a different, publicly available DNS to resolve the address but should give the result mentioned above.

If #3 works but #2 does not then you need to change your DNS settings. 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Google's OpenDNS) are excellent choices for DNS if you don't need internal DNS resolution for a private network.

To change your DNS settings:

1. Press <kbd>[image: win10key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key.
2. Type `control ncpa.cpl` into the run dialog
3. Click `Ok`.
4. Right click on the network adapter you are using
5. Click `Properties` from the drop down.
6. Double-Click `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)`
7. Select the `Use the following DNS server addresses` radio button
8. Type `8.8.8.8` into the "Preferred DNS Server" Box
9. Type `8.8.4.4` into the "ALternate DNS Server" Box
10. Click `Ok`
11. Click `Ok`
12. Perform the above DNS tests again.

### Disable Browser Proxy

Your web browser may be configured to use a proxy. A quick test for this would be to telnet to an http server.

1. Open the command prompt.
2. Type `telnet annapuma.onsite-crt.com 80`

You should see:

```
Trying 144.217.115.63...
Connected to annapuma.onsite-crt.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

3. type `GET /index.html`

You should see:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://annapuma.onsite-crt.com/index.html">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at annapuma.onsite-crt.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

If this works and you still can't open pages in your browser then the issue is likely browser related and proxy settings may well be the issue. Bitdefender provides [a guide](https://www.bitdefender.com/support/how-to-remove-proxy-settings-in-your-browser-1910.html) for removing proxy settings that covers the most common browsers.

### Something Else

There are quite a few other possibilities but these are by far the most likely. I would need more info if these do not solve your problem. If you manage to collect any additional info feel free to add the additional info to your question and drop a comment so I'll be notified.

Comment: When I `nslookup google.com` it shows:

Comment: When I `nslookup google.com` it shows: `DNS Request Timeout.
 Timeout was 2 Seconds.
Server: UnKnown
Address: 10.1.1.11
DNS Request Timeout.
 Timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS Request Timeout.
 Timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS Request Timeout.
 Timeout was 2 seconds.
`
But even after changing the "Preferred DNS Server" to `8.8.8.8` and "Alternate DNS Server" to `8.8.4.4`, it rmains the same i.e.
`DNS Request Timeout.
 Timeout was 2 Seconds.
Server: UnKnown
Address: 8.8.8.8
DNS Request Timeout.
 Timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS Request Timeout.
 Timeout was 2 seconds` . How to Proceed now?

Comment: Well now, that's rather interesting. Confirm that you can at least reach 8.8.8.8 by trying to ping it. Also, do you have any kind of firewall programs on your computer?

Comment: I can ping `10.1.1.11` but it shows "requested time out" for `8.8.8.8`. Also, when I connect the LAN and open browser it asks for my "Proxy Credentials" but the websites don't get loaded. It keeps on showing "performing TLS Handshake" at the bottom. I have turned off the firewall.

Comment: Ok. There's a lot of info there that needs to be in your question above so other people can chew on it. The most interesting is that you can't ping 8.8.8.8. That implies you aren't connected to the internet after all. Go ahead and edit your question to include that you can't ping Google OpenDNS and that it's asking you for proxy credentials when you open your browser. Also that you can't resolve dns addresses with as your DNS 10.1.1.11 but you can ping 10.1.1.11.

Comment: There's a lot going wrong at once... it's hard to see how they would be connected. You may have multiple configuration issues instead of just one.

Comment: I am basically using Intranet of college. Other friends of mine whose LAN is working also can't ping `8.8.8.8` but can ping the proxy servers like me. I somehow feel that the problem has got something to do with the "Performing TLS Handshake" thing. This happens across all browsers that i have tried.

Comment: Sounds like the college is blocking access to outside DNS servers. Try pinging... `216.58.219.164`. Have those friends try too. TLS is an encryption standard (the modern version of SSL) used for encrypting communication between two devices. Legitimate proxies often allow you to connect to them via encryption to protect the content of your communications. I can see a college implementing something like that. If the TLS handshake was failing it would cause no end of trouble... but it's rather unlikely for such to fail unless something else is causing it to.

Comment: It's also possible the college blocks _everrything_ that doesn't go out via the proxies. But if failing to connect to the proxy servers is the problem you're gonna need to get the college sysadmin's invloved in fixing the issue. That includes if something is keeping a TLS connection from succeeding to them.

Comment: Ok. Tried pinging `216.58.219.164`  but it shows "Requested Time Out". Also, When I am using Proxifier it shows some number in "Bytes Sent" but displays "0" in "Bytes received". I am being able to ping the proxy servers. So, that doesn't look to be an issue.

Comment: `216.58.219.164` is `www.google.com`. So yeah. Seems the problem is you aren't connecting to the colleges proxy and they don't let anything in or out that doesn't use their proxy. It's difficult for me to help with their proxy as it will be implementation specific. You need to talk to the school's IT people to fix that.

Comment: My friends whose LAN is up and running also couldn't ping `216.58.219.164`. I am connecting to the colleges proxy as my WiFi works fine with those Proxy settings only.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping your default gateway?

Can you ping your DNS server?

Note: contrary to [Cliff Armstrong's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1250981/401839) suggesting an RFC 1918 address is a problem, I suspect that isn't a problem.  I suspect your system may have picked that up from the DHCP server, and that may work fine.

If you can communicate with your default gateway, then the issue may be with the network.  This may be outside of your control.  Perhaps your network is shutting you down until you appease the network's requirements.  Maybe you need to sign up for a (perhaps free) account.  Maybe you need to agree to some terms.  Maybe you need to point your web browser to a specific address to be able to have your traffic get to the Internet.

Contact your ISP.  That may mean contacting a help desk staffed by the college.  Get their help.  They may be able to help you if you have a common problem.  They also might be the only people who can help you if you're dealing with some specific scenarios.

If the college's help desk isn't available now (perhaps being closed on weekends), check back later, or ask a fellow student who has had more success.  (Although, if the issue is that you need to create an account for yourself, your fellow student may be able to help provide some useful information, but may not be able to fully resolve this for you.)

Comment: I can ping the default gateway as well as DNS Server. I have got all the reuired proxy IDs. Until a few days back, i was able to browse internet by following the same process. I am unable to figure the problem.